# Number of ways to arrange the letters in CACHES so that none of the letters are in their original position

Tags: combinatorics

**Original question** (Too long for title): Number of ways to arrange the letters in CACHES so that the letter C is not in the first or third position and none of the letters A, H, E, S is in its original position

The given answer is 84.

**My approach**: I think it should be equal to the number of derangements of a set of size 6 minus the number of derangements where the 3rd C is swapped to the 1st position or where the 3rd C is swapped to the 1st position, or

$d_6$ - N(derangements where $C_1$ is in 3rd position) - N(derangements $C_3$ is in 1st position) + N(derangements where $C_1$ is in 3rd position and $C_3$ is in 1st position)

= 265 - $d_5$ - $d_5$ + $d_4$ = 265 - 2*44 + 9 = 186

Can someone point out what is wrong with my method, and hopefully tell me how it can be solved this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are assuming that N(derangements where $C_1$ is in third position) is equivalent to $d_5$. Same for $C_3$ and first position.

To understand this, let's represent derangements in a different way. Set up a grid (I'm using matrices) in the following way
\begin{bmatrix}
   &A&B&C&D&E&F\\
 A &1&0&0&0&0&0\\
 B &0&1&0&0&0&0\\
 C &0&0&1&0&0&0\\
 D &0&0&0&1&0&0\\
 E &0&0&0&0&1&0\\
 F &0&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
Now we can understand the number of derangements of ABCDEF as the number of ways to choose 6 different entries that are 0, one from every row and column (excluding the row and column with letters of course).

This grid is a representation of your problem.
\begin{bmatrix}
\ &C&A&C&H&E&S \\
C&1&0&1&0&0&0 \\
A&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\
C&1&0&1&0&0&0 \\
H&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\
E&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\
S&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}

You tried to solve it by ignoring that the Cs were the same and approaching it like a normal derangement.
\begin{bmatrix}
\ &C_1&A_2&C_3&H_4&E_5&S_6 \\
C_1&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
A_2&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\
C_3&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\
H_4&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\
E_5&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\
S_6&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}

Then you subtracted the number of ways that $C_1$ was in the third slot (i.e. "remove" the third column or slot as well as the first row).
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\ &C_1&A_2&   &H_4&E_5&S_6 \\
   & & & & & &  \\
A_2&0&1& &0&0&0 \\
C_3&0&0& &0&0&0 \\
H_4&0&0& &1&0&0 \\
E_5&0&0& &0&1&0 \\
S_6&0&0& &0&0&1
\end{bmatrix} =>
\begin{bmatrix}
\ &C_1&A_2&H_4&E_5&S_6 \\
A_2&0&1&0&0&0 \\
C_3&0&0&0&0&0 \\
H_4&0&0&1&0&0 \\
E_5&0&0&0&1&0 \\
S_6&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Same for $C_3$ and the first slot.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\ &   &A_2&C_3&H_4&E_5&S_6 \\
C_1& &0&0&0&0&0 \\
A_2& &1&0&0&0&0 \\
   & & & & & &  \\
H_4& &0&0&1&0&0 \\
E_5& &0&0&0&1&0 \\
S_6& &0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix} =>
\begin{bmatrix}
\ &A_2&C_3&H_4&E_5&S_6 \\
C_1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
A_2&1&0&0&0&0 \\
H_4&0&0&1&0&0 \\
E_5&0&0&0&1&0 \\
S_6&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

And finally, because you subtracted too much, you added in the extra case where both of the Cs were switched.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\ &   &A_2&   &H_4&E_5&S_6 \\
   & & & & & &  \\
A_2& &1& &0&0&0 \\
   & & & & & &  \\
H_4& &0& &1&0&0 \\
E_5& &0& &0&1&0 \\
S_6& &0& &0&0&1
\end{bmatrix} =>
\begin{bmatrix}
\ &A_2&H_4&E_5&S_6 \\
A_2&1&0&0&0 \\
H_4&0&1&0&0 \\
E_5&0&0&1&0 \\
S_6&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

However, looking at the second (or third) grid:
\begin{bmatrix}
\ &C_1&A_2&H_4&E_5&S_6 \\
A_2&0&1&0&0&0 \\
C_3&0&0&0&0&0 \\
H_4&0&0&1&0&0 \\
E_5&0&0&0&1&0 \\
S_6&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
you can clearly see that this is not a representation of a derangement.

Does that make sense? I couldn't think of another way to explain it.

**Edit:**

Here's a much better way to explain where you went wrong then how I did originally.

The problem is you are assuming that $N(\text{derangements where }C_1\text{ is fixed in the third position}) = d_5$. This is wrong because the position of $C_3$ is independent of the derangements where $C_1$ is in third position, i.e. $C_3$ can go into *any* of the other five positions and is therefore not a derangement. Same vice versa.

However, if we make a derangement by fixing $C_1$ in the third position and considering the first position to be the original position of $C_3$, then this is equivalent to a derangement of a set of size 5. Again, same vice versa. As for the instance where $C_1$ and $C_3$ are switched, it is easy to show that this is equivalent to a derangement of a set of size 4 - as you have already done. So in conclusion:

$$N(\text{"derangements" of CACHES}) = N(\text{derangements of }C_1A_2C_3H_3E_4S_5) - N(\text{derangements where $C_3$ is fixed and $C_1$ is considered to be originally in third position}) - N(\text{derangements where $C_1$ is fixed and $C_3$ is considered to be originally in first position}) - N(\text{derangements where $C_1$ and $C_3$ are fixed in switched positions}) = d_6 - d_5 - d_5 - d_4 = 168$$

---

However, this is different from your answer of 84. So either 84 is the wrong answer or the question is not described clearly. I wrote a program (in Python) to calculate the number of derangements of CACHES:

---

from itertools import product

# Get all possible permutations of six integers that are 0-5
# l = [(0,0,0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,0,0,1), (0,0,0,0,0,2), ...]
l = [x for x in product([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], repeat=6)]
# Filter it down to unique arrangements of the integers 0-5
# l2 = [(0,1,2,3,4,5), (0,1,2,3,5,4), ...]
l2 = [x for x in l if sorted(list(set(x)))==sorted(x)]

s = 'CACHES'
# Create a list of all permutations of CACHES
y = [s[a]+s[b]+s[c]+s[d]+s[e]+s[f] for a,b,c,d,e,f in l2]

# Remove permutations with first letter being C
y1 = [x for x in y if x[0]!='C']

# Remove permutations with first letter being A
y2 = [x for x in y1 if x[1]!='A']

# Etc.
y3 = [x for x in y2 if x[2]!='C']
y4 = [x for x in y3 if x[3]!='H']
y5 = [x for x in y4 if x[4]!='E']
y6 = [x for x in y5 if x[5]!='S']

print(len(y6))
# Prints out "168"

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to counting the number of functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that $f(1) \neq 1, 3$, $f(3) \neq 1,3$, $f(i) \neq i$, $i = 2,4,5,6$. The $(1,3)$ pair must be mapped to two among $2,4,5,6$. This can be done in 6 ways. Suppose that $1 \rightarrow 2, 3 \rightarrow 4$. Then we have to map $5, 6, 2, 4$ to $5,6,1,3$. This, by inclusion exclusion principle is $$4! - 3! - 3! + 2! = 14$$ The same is the case when we map $1,3$ to any other pair among $2,4,5,6$. Thus the total number of ways is $14 \times 6 = 84$.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the answer 168 from Noah May and the 84 apparently given with the problem is just a factor of 2: In Noah's calculation the two C's are still considered different and a swap between them produces a different solution, while there is no such difference between the C's in the problem. In other words, each of the 84 solutions of the problem, like

$$\mathrm{ACSCHE}$$

maps two 2 solutions in Noah's solution:

$$\mathrm{AC_1SC_3HE\space and\space AC_3SC_1HE}  $$